HLSL: Force order of floating point operations to prevent rounding error
When writing shaders in HLSL, sometimes you can run into very large floating point numbers, and with large floating point numbers, they struggle to maintain precision.  When I wrote the blow code, I intended for the large, but very round numbers to subtract before adding the small, fractional number.  But, the HLSL compiler seems to be doing the operations in the opposite order presumably for optimization.  It just produces results that are unacceptably bad.
jdsatepoch is 2460432.5
jdsatepochF is .605138

float computeEpoch = (jdsatepoch-2433281.5) + jdsatepochF; 

Expected value: 27152.105569  << tiny error    (Good)
Actual value: 27151.5         << MASSIVE error (Bad)

I can't seem to find any mechanism to "force" the compiler to maintain the order of floating point operations so that it doesn't blow away all my fractional precision.  Is there some mechanism to say "please specifically perform these operations in this order"?

So you want confirmation that the compiler can change the order of operations even if explicitly fixed? Did you try to put the first difference into a temporary variable? Can you try (a1-a0)*1.0+b? // You know that float only has about 7 valid digits, so that the accuracy of the reference result is unrealistic?

Doing your recommendation makes no impact.  Using a temporary variable seems to work, if I specifically contrive a situation where I use that variable later.  But I seem to be running into cases where even that doesn't work.
And it's ok if it's not exactly that, but, it should be able to represent 1/16M fractional component.

It takes some effort to make a compiler this stupid about parentheses. I do not see any direct method to circumvent that. Are there any compiler options or directives available that disable this heavy optimization of the math operations?

It seems the precise keyword is exactly what I needed!  I just answered below.

It seems like, at least in my cases, prefixing the floating point variable with the "precise" tag fixes it in this case.  I don't know if this is always the case, but some other things I noticed along the way:

Using a temporary variable and using the result of that temporary variable later
#pragma skip_optimizations d3d11 (the drivers still optimize)

The application of the precise tag seems to also depend on other related variables also being marked as precise.  This outcome seems pretty robust.
precise float jdsatepoch = tledat0.y;
float jdsatepochF = tledat0.z;
precise float computeEpoch = (jdsatepoch) + jdsatepochF;
precise float initialTimeMinutes = ( (jdDay - 2433281.5 - jdsatepoch) + jdFrac - jdsatepochF)*24.0 * 60.0;

